# Scrapy - Copying only the xpath into .csv file

Tags: pandas, scrapy

I have many other scripts with simlar basic code that work, but when I run this spider in cmd, and I open the .csv file to look at the "titles" saved, I get the xpath copied into excel. Any idea why?

```
import scrapy


class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movie'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title?start=1']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title?start=1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/h3/a')
        pass
        print(titles)


        for title in titles:
            yield {'Title': title}
```

--- Try Two Below:------

```
for subject in titles:
            yield {
                'Title': subject.xpath('.//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'Runtime': subject.xpath('.//p[@class="text-muted"]/span/text()').extract_first(),
                'Description': subject.xpath('.//p[@class="text-muted"]/p/text()').extract_first(),
                'Director': subject.xpath('.//*[@id="main"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'Rating': subject.xpath('.//div[@class="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating"]/strong/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

Comment: You need to call `extract()` on your xpath.

Answer (score 3):

Use `extract()` or  `extract_first()`, also use shorter and more capacious notation for xpath:

```
import scrapy


class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movie'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title?start=1']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title?start=1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        subjects = response.xpath('//div[@class="lister-item mode-advanced"]')

        for subject in subjects:
            yield {
                'Title': subject.xpath('.//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'Rating': subject.xpath('.//div[@class="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating"]/strong/text()').extract_first(),
                'Runtime': subject.xpath('.//span[@class="runtime"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'Description': subject.xpath('.//p[@class="text-muted"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'Directior': subject.xpath('.//p[contains(text(), "Director")]/a[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: View code in your answer for my next questions, essentially I am now trying to add a "Ratings" portion,, but not sure why my code is note working again :(

Comment: @pes04 What code did you add? Try this:                                            
'Rating': subject.xpath('.//div[@class="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating"]/strong/text()').extract_first(),

Comment: Hi , I am so sorry, I guess it got deleted, Please new view code in my original question. I essentially tried to show you my approach  for Runtime,Description,Directior as I am getting None for all and I Just dont get why. I feel like I am following same logic you did for Ratings. @starpony

Comment: thank you. For Runtime - why is it .//div and not .//p ? I just dont get what I am not doing wrong, I am now trying to get Gross Revenue: **'Gross Revenue': subject.xpath('.//span[@class="text-muted]/text()').extract_first(),** but still getting no results.

Comment: @pes04 For Gross = 'Gross Revenue': subject.xpath('.//span[@name="nv" and contains(text(), "$")]/text()').extract_first()